# Questions about Nested if Statements for Java

Tags: java, if-statement

So the question my teacher wrote on the white board is: **Input product Name, Quantity, price. Compute the total amount. If total amount is greater than 2000 discount is 5%, if total amount is greater than 5000 discount is 10%, if greater than 10000 discount is 20%**

I know that you have to do this kind of format.

```
if (cost > 2000)
 discount = 0.05;
```

I would put in the correct things before than like

```
String prodName;
int qty, price;
double cost;
double discount;
```

I know what I put there is wrong but I think that's how the format of it goes before doing the nested if statement. I really need help on this. I don't need to be given the answers for this because that's spoon-feeding to the max level. I just need some pointers and a guide in order to find out what to do.

Comment: P.S. I also have to get the Net Amount somehow

Comment: take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Do you need to do this with nested ifs, or is that just your idea of doing it?

Comment: @MrLister That's my idea of doing it since i have no other format other than the one my professor taught me, which are the basic things like finding out the prelim, midterm, final grades or finding the total amount of something and putting in the product name

Comment: @IzzyDeLeon By net amount do you mean the cost after the discount?

Comment: @DizzyCode haha yes : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to read your book thoroughly. Obviously [this can be a good start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html). First learn how `if-then` works, next `if-then-else` and finally `if-then-else if-then-else`. Now lets analyze your question:

> Input product Name, Quantity, price. Compute the total amount. If total amount is greater than 2000 discount is 5%, if total amount is greater than 5000 discount is 10%, if greater than 10000 discount is 20%.

Clearly you are going to set one variable, lets call it `discount`, with checking some condition. For explanation, say if the total amount is *greater than 10000*, then you are going to set `discount = 20%`. But careful, when *total amount* is *greater than 10000*, it also leads *total amount* is *greater than 5000 or 2000* too! Then are you going to set `discount = 10%` or `discount = 5%` respectively? No, you are not.

Hence, to solve your problem, if a higher prioritize condition is already matched, you are not going to check any other conditions. So we will do the following:

```
discount;
total_amount = some Cost you calculated/inputted
if(total_amount > 10000) {
    discount = 0.2;
} else if(total_amount > 5000) {
    discount = 0.05;
} else if(total_amount > 2000) {
    discount = 0.01;
} else {
    discount = 0.00; // no discount for you coz total_amount less than or equal to 2000
}
```

Now what happens here? If the first test expression is `true` (`total_amount > 10000`), it executes the code inside the braces `{ }` just below it and no other block is executed. But if the first test expression is `false`, it checks the second test expression (`total_amount > 5000`). If the second test expression is `true`, it executes the statement/s inside the braces `{ }` just below it and no other block is executed. This process continues. If all the test expression are `false`, code/s inside `else` is executed and the control of program jumps below the `if-else`.

When you fully understand `if-else` then you can solve this problem in many different ways. Best of luck.

Comment: I'll read my book very thoroughly. Since everybody is giving jsut about the same answer, I'm starting to wonder if I actually have to insert the String prodName; int qty, price; and things like those

Comment: The question you asked mainly focused on using _if-else_ that's why nobody says about the _other_ variables. If your program needs them, of course you must use them!

Comment: Thank you! I'm starting to get the hang of this! I think your comment helped me out the most. You didn't include how to get the net amount but that's basic math anyway so I can just compute for that. I'm only having trouble making the "total amount" and the "net amount" to print out. Otherwise, I'm all good.  
EDIT: my total amount is listed as double = total_amount. When I try to write System.out.println("Total Amount: " +total_amount); it becomes an error. I copied your example as a guide, so what I have on my Eclipse is what you gave me

Answer (score 1):

first declare all your variables like you did:

```
String prodName="";
int qty, price;
double cost; //your cost will be stored here
double discount =0;
```

Then do your calculations

```
if (cost > 2000 && cost <= 5000)
   discount = 0.05;
else if(cost > 5000 && cost <= 10000){
   discount = 0.1;
}else if(cost > 10000){
   discount = 0.2;
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if I even put down the right variables, though. That's just my idea of doing it, but i don't think it's necessarily correct.

Comment: @IzzyDeLeon this is basically how you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few pointers, you are to compare the price, if you do it in reverse order you could do :

```
if (cost > 10000)
    discount = 0.2;
else if (cost > 5000)
    discount = 0.1;
else if (cost > 2000)
    discount = 0.05;
```

This is handy because you aren't nesting if statements and it still is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cost > 10000)
    discount = 0.2;
else if(cost > 5000){
    discount = 0.1;
}else if(cost > 2000){
    discount = 0.05;
} else {
    discount = 0;
}
double total = cost - (cost * discount);
```

When using if and else ifs if the first if statement is true then that code is executed and none of the other else ifs are checked. If the first if is false then each else if following the if are checked in the order they appear. If one of them is true then that code is executed and none of the others are checked. However, if none are true and you had an else block that code would get executed.

Comment: last else (if discount is a local variable and has not been initialize):   else discount = 0;

Comment: It should give 0. That way when you subtract cost from discount * cost it gives you just the cost without any discount applied.

Comment: Hi Casey, thank you for the help. I have a problem since I've never dealt with this one before. I'm wondering what you would put at the top before writing the if and else statement. I copied what Luthando Loot gave me which is: String prodName="";
  int qty, price;
  double cost;//your cost will be stored here
  double discount = 0;
but now it's asking for the cost on the double cost part. I would try to input the 3 numbers that i have which is 10000, 5000, 2000 but it wouldn't work.

Comment: What he gave should be correct. What do you mean it didn't work? What happened?

Comment: @Casey it only says the the "cost" has not been initialized. Whenever I try to initialize it, it would ask me to input a number.

Comment: Are you doing int cost = 10000; ? Or are you saying you need to read input from a user and assign it to the cost variable?

Comment: @Casey Nevermind I've got it : ) I used the formula you gave me to get the net amount. Although, I tried changing the name of double total to double netamount but I got an error. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it nested and in the order that the question asks if it will be easier to understand. We just update the discount as necessary. Note that the other answers might be prettier, but this is a way to do it nested:

```
double cost = ...;
double discount = 0.0;

if (cost > 2000)
{
   discount = 0.05;
   if (cost > 5000) 
   { 
      discount = 0.10;
      if (cost > 10000)
      {
         discount = 0.20;
      } 
   }  
}

cost = cost - (cost * discount);
```

You could do it backwards, or with `else if` and `else` statements too.

Comment: these guys dont like to see good answers, i also have a downvote

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cost > 10000)
    discount = 0.2;
else if (cost > 5000)
    discount = 0.1;
else if (cost > 2000)
    discount = 0.05;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code can help you......

```
if (cost > 10000)
    discount = 0.2;
else if (cost > 5000)
    discount = 0.1;
else if (cost > 2000)
    discount = 0.05;
else
System.out.println("cost is less than 2000 hence no discount applied");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think nested if statements are necessary in this case. Instead you can reverse the order of the if statements so that it first checks for `cost > 10000`, then `cost > 5000`, and finally `cost > 2000`.

Also, if the net amount you mentioned is the cost after discount, then you can do a simple calculation after the if statements. It would look something like this:

```
double discount = 0;

if (cost > 10000){
    discount = 0.2;
}
else if(cost > 5000){
    //similar to above, won't spoon-feed this
}
else if(cost > 2000){
    //similar to above, won't spoon-feed this
}

double netAmount = cost * (1 - discount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for nested `if` statements, but you could seriously shorten the solution to this problem using a `ternary` operator, especially since this is primarily used for assigning a value to `discount`. Probably considerably more complex than what you were looking for but this *could* work:

```
double cost, netAmount;
//get cost 
double discount = cost > 10000 ? 0.2 : cost > 5000 ? 0.1 : cost > 2000 ? 0.05 : 0;
netAmount = discount * cost;
```

**Brief Explanation**

This works just like nested `if` statements, but it's a neater, if less readable, way of writing them. Each boolean expression, such as

```
cost > 10000
```

is evaluated to either or true or false, as per all boolean expressions. The values after the `ternary` operator, the `?`, are assigned if the expression returns true. Values after the `:` are assigned if the expression returns false. In this case if cost is greater than 10000, the value 0.2 is assigned. If cost is less than 10000, we want to evaluate another boolean expression so we nest another boolean expression like so:

```
cost > 10000 ? 0.2 : cost < 5000...
```

The final `:` indicates what value will be assigned should all other expression evaluate to false, just like a terminating `else` statement in an `if - else` block.